# node-opcua "Transaction has timed out"

Tags: node.js, opc, opc-ua, node-opcua

I have setup monitoring on couple of nodeIds using `node-opcua` package.
It works fine for some time but then started printing some timeout messages.

Here's the `journalctl` output of my service:

```
Apr 07 08:02:02 test-machine myservice[559]:  Timeout .... waiting for response for  ReadRequest { /*RequestHeader*/
Apr 07 08:02:02 test-machine myservice[559]:  authenticationToken           /* NodeId                           */: ns=0;i=50
Apr 07 08:02:02 test-machine myservice[559]:  timeStamp                     /* UtcTime                          */: 2017-04-07T15:01:02.501Z
Apr 07 08:02:02 test-machine myservice[559]:  requestHandle                 /* IntegerId                        */: 334               0x14e
Apr 07 08:02:02 test-machine myservice[559]:  returnDiagnostics             /* UInt32                           */: 0               0x0
Apr 07 08:02:02 test-machine myservice[559]:  auditEntryId                  /* UAString                         */:
Apr 07 08:02:02 test-machine myservice[559]:  timeoutHint                   /* UInt32                           */: 0               0x0
Apr 07 08:02:02 test-machine myservice[559]:  additionalHeader              /* ExtensionObject                  */: null
Apr 07 08:02:02 test-machine myservice[559]: };
Apr 07 08:02:02 test-machine myservice[559]:  warning :  Transaction has timed out
Apr 07 08:02:15 test-machine myservice[559]:  Timeout .... waiting for response for  ReadRequest { /*RequestHeader*/
Apr 07 08:02:15 test-machine myservice[559]:  authenticationToken           /* NodeId                           */: ns=0;i=50
Apr 07 08:02:15 test-machine myservice[559]:  timeStamp                     /* UtcTime                          */: 2017-04-07T15:01:15.835Z
Apr 07 08:02:15 test-machine myservice[559]:  requestHandle                 /* IntegerId                        */: 335               0x14f
Apr 07 08:02:15 test-machine myservice[559]:  returnDiagnostics             /* UInt32                           */: 0               0x0
Apr 07 08:02:15 test-machine myservice[559]:  auditEntryId                  /* UAString                         */:
Apr 07 08:02:15 test-machine myservice[559]:  timeoutHint                   /* UInt32                           */: 0               0x0
Apr 07 08:02:15 test-machine myservice[559]:  additionalHeader              /* ExtensionObject                  */: null
Apr 07 08:02:15 test-machine myservice[559]: };
Apr 07 08:02:15 test-machine myservice[559]:  warning :  Transaction has timed out
Apr 07 08:02:29 test-machine myservice[559]:  Timeout .... waiting for response for  ReadRequest { /*RequestHeader*/
Apr 07 08:02:29 test-machine myservice[559]:  authenticationToken           /* NodeId                           */: ns=0;i=50
Apr 07 08:02:29 test-machine myservice[559]:  timeStamp                     /* UtcTime                          */: 2017-04-07T15:01:29.169Z
Apr 07 08:02:29 test-machine myservice[559]:  requestHandle                 /* IntegerId                        */: 336               0x150
Apr 07 08:02:29 test-machine myservice[559]:  returnDiagnostics             /* UInt32                           */: 0               0x0
Apr 07 08:02:29 test-machine myservice[559]:  auditEntryId                  /* UAString                         */:
Apr 07 08:02:29 test-machine myservice[559]:  timeoutHint                   /* UInt32                           */: 0               0x0
Apr 07 08:02:29 test-machine myservice[559]:  additionalHeader              /* ExtensionObject                  */: null
Apr 07 08:02:29 test-machine myservice[559]: };
Apr 07 08:02:29 test-machine myservice[559]:  warning :  Transaction has timed out
Apr 07 08:03:01 test-machine myservice[559]:  Timeout .... waiting for response for  OpenSecureChannelRequest { /*RequestHeader*/
Apr 07 08:03:01 test-machine myservice[559]:  authenticationToken           /* NodeId                           */: ns=0;i=0
Apr 07 08:03:01 test-machine myservice[559]:  timeStamp                     /* UtcTime                          */: 2017-04-07T15:02:01.928Z
Apr 07 08:03:01 test-machine myservice[559]:  requestHandle                 /* IntegerId                        */: 337               0x151
Apr 07 08:03:01 test-machine myservice[559]:  returnDiagnostics             /* UInt32                           */: 0               0x0
Apr 07 08:03:01 test-machine myservice[559]:  auditEntryId                  /* UAString                         */: null
Apr 07 08:03:01 test-machine myservice[559]:  timeoutHint                   /* UInt32                           */: 0               0x0
Apr 07 08:03:01 test-machine myservice[559]:  additionalHeader              /* ExtensionObject                  */: null
Apr 07 08:03:01 test-machine myservice[559]: };
Apr 07 08:03:01 test-machine myservice[559]: Warning: securityToken hasn't been renewed
```

Basically I want to keep the monitoring going forever and get the publishes every 15 minutes. So it would be really great if someone can help me with the parameters for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server you could take a look at this [post](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/issues/141).

In the post they state that, when you set up your client, the `requestedLifetimeCount * requestedPublishingInterval` shall be set to at least the `PublishRequest.RequestHeader.timeoutHint`:

```js
var options = {
  requestedPublishingInterval: 1000, // check on server
  requestedMaxKeepAliveCount: 2,
  requestedLifetimeCount: 100, // check on server
  maxNotificationsPerPublish: 10,
  publishingEnabled: true,
  priority: 10,
}

var subscription = new opcua.ClientSubscription(opcSession, options);
```